# Hulek's proof about local representations of regular differentials on smooth curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**Preliminary definitions**

Let $C$ be a smooth algebraic curve.

In Hulek's *Elementary Algebraic Geometry*, a differential form on an open subset $U \subset C$ is defined to be a section
$$ \varphi : U \to \bigcup_{x \in U} m_x / m_x^2 , \ \ \ \ \ \varphi(x) \in m_x / m_x^2,$$
where for each $x \in U$, $m_x$ is the maximal ideal in the local ring at $x$. (This local ring is a DVR, since $C$ is a smooth curve.)

$\varphi$ is *regular* at $p$ if there exist functions $f_1, \dots, f_l, g_1, \dots, g_l$ regular in a neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ with $V \subset U$ such that $\varphi = f_1 dg_1 + \dots + f_l dg_l $ on $V$. The differential $dg_i$ is defined by the expression
$$ dg_i(x) = g - g(x) \ \ \ \text{mod } m_x^2.$$
One can easily show that this definition gives rise to calculus-style identities such as $d(h_1h_2) = h_1 dh_2 + h_2 dh_1$.

If $t$ is a generator of the (principal) ideal $m_x$, then we say that $t$ is a *local parameter* at $x$.

**The claim**

Hulek claims to prove the following:

> Let $t$ be a local parameter at a point $P \in C$. Then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $P$ such that every regular differential form on $U$ can be represented as $g dt$ for some $g$ that is regular on $U$.

However, Hulek's proof looks suspect, and I've been having trouble making sense of it.

---

**Hulek's proof**

Hulek starts by assuming that $C \subset \mathbb A_k^n$, and introduces coordinates $x_1, \dots, x_n$. In his notation, the ideal $I(C)$ that defines $C$ is generated by the polynomials $F_1, \dots , F_l \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$.

Hulek observes that least one of the $x_i$'s must be a local parameter at $P$; without loss of generality, he supposes that $t_1 := x_1$ is a local parameter at $P$. He also observes that the Jacobian matrix $ \left[ \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j} (P) \right]$ has rank $n - 1$. I agree with all of this.

Hulek then immediately states that we can use equations of the form $0 = dF_i = \sum_j \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j} dx_j$ to locally express each $dx_i$ as $dx_i = h_i dt_1$ for some regular $h_i$.

This step puzzles me. How do you construct these local representations for the $dx_i$'s? How do you make use of the fact that $dF_i=0$, or the fact that the Jacobian matrix has rank $n -1$? What is the significance of the local parameter being one of the coordinate functions? I've stared at this for a while and I just can't see what algebraic trick Hulek is getting at.

Anyway, from here onwards, Hulek infers that any regular differential form can be locally expressed as $g dt_1$ for some regular $g$, and a few sentences later he concludes that the same kind of representation can be achieved with respect to an *arbitrary* local parameter $t$. But all of this depends on that magic step earlier on, which I can't make sense of.

---

**My approach**

I came up with a different approach myself, which is far more involved than what's written in Hulek's book.

Let $t$ be *any* local parameter at $P$. $t$ generates the maximal ideal $m_P$ in the local ring at $P$, so certainly $t$ is a basis vector for the 1-dimensional $k$-vector space $m_P / m_P^2$.

It is well known that there is a canonical $k$-vector space isomorphism between $m_P / m_P^2$ and the cotangent space at $P$. This cotangent space is the dual of the vector space that is the tangent line at $P$, and can be viewed as $k^n / \text{Span}(\nabla F_1 (p), \dots, \nabla F_l (p))$, where (like in Hulek's proof) the $F_i$'s are the defining equations for $C$, and $\nabla F_i (p) := (\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_1}(p), \dots,  \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_n}(p))$.

Via this vector space isomorphism, $t \in m_P / m_P^2$ maps to $\nabla t (p) := (\frac{\partial t}{\partial x_1}(p), \dots,  \frac{\partial t}{\partial x_n}(p)) \in k^n / \text{Span}(\nabla F_1 (p), \dots, \nabla F_l (p) )$. The fact that $\nabla t(p)$ is a basis vector for this 1-dimensional vector space means that we can find some $F_{k_1}, \dots, F_{k_{n-1}}$ from amongst the $F_i$'s such that the $n \times n$ matrix
\begin{align*}
M := \begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{\partial t}{\partial x_1}   & \dots & \frac{\partial t}{\partial x_n} \\ \tfrac{\partial F_{k_1}}{\partial x_1} & \dots & \frac{\partial F_{k_1}}{\partial x_n} \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ \tfrac{\partial F_{k_{n - 1}}}{\partial x_1}  & \dots & \frac{\partial F_{k_{n- 1}}}{\partial x_n} \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
has non-vanishing determinant at $P$, and therefore, has non-vanishing determinant on a Zariski-open neighbourhood $U$ of $P$.

[Note that what I have shown is stronger than Hulek's observation that the Jacobian matrix for $F$ has rank $n - 1$ on a neighbourhood of $P$.]

We have the "calculus" identities
\begin{align*}
 \begin{bmatrix} dt \\ dF_{k_1} \\ \vdots \\ dF_{k_{n-1}} \end{bmatrix} = M \begin{bmatrix} dx_1 \\ \vdots \\ dx_n \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Inverting this, we get
\begin{align*}
 \begin{bmatrix} dx_1 \\ \vdots \\ dx_n \end{bmatrix} = M^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} dt \\ dF_{k_1} \\ \vdots \\ dF_{k_{n-1}} \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Now observe that $dF_{k_1} = \dots = dF_{k_{n-1}} = 0$ on $C$ since $F_{k_1}, \dots , F_{k_{n-1}}$ are defining equations for $C$. The entries in $M^{-1}$ are regular on $U$ since $\text{det}(M)$ is non-vanishing on $U$. Thus, we've managed to express each $dx_j$ in the form $h_j dt$ for some $h_j$ that is regular on $U$.

Finally, given an arbitrary regular function $g$ on $U$, we can write
$$ dg = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1} dx_1 + \dots + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n} dx_n = \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1} h_1 + \dots + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n} h_n \right) dt.$$
The expression inside the brackets is regular on $U$, so we're done.

---

**The ask**

I'd be grateful for input on any or all of the following:

- What does Hulek have in mind in that magic step in his argument?
- Assuming Hulek's argument works, how similar is his argument to mine? Perhaps Hulek's intended approach draws upon key ideas that I missed in my approach?
- If Hulek's argument doesn't work (or if we can't make sense of it), then is my argument correct - and if so, are there any authoritative resources that use an argument like mine? (I do try to be careful but I get a little paranoid when I completely rewrite proofs in books.)

Comment: It's been over a week since I asked this. I'm inclined to just take my alternative approach as the proof.

Comment: Although at the time, I came up with my approach by algebraic trial and error, I've come to see that it's actually quite intuitive. If we were doing differential geometry rather than algebraic geometry, then the rank theorem for submersions tells us that we can find a local chart for $k[x_1, ... , x_n]$ whose coordinates are $t$ and $n-1$ of the $f_i$'s. This is the gist of what's going on.